# SoundCloud Custom Player/jQuery: remove track from list with beforeRender

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a track-list from a SoundCloud user, based on a given tags using jQuery and the Custom Player (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player).
The (simplified) loop works, but the delete-function isn't removing the object.

```
$('.soundcloud').scPlayer({
    links: [{
        url: "http://soundcloud.com/myusername",
        title: "http://soundcloud.com/myusername"
    }],
    beforeRender : function(tracksData) {
        $.each(tracksData, function(index, item) {
            tags = item.tag_list.toLowerCase().split(' ');
            if(jQuery.inArray("mytag", tags)>1) {
                 console.log('this track is not allowed');
                 delete tracksData.item // this is my problem, right here
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hiya, Can you please flick a jsfiddle I might be able to help you out, cheers!

Comment: Hi! I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/v6bys/ Markup is a little weird, but that's not the problem. I would like to see only the second track, since that one is tagged with "Dutch" and the first one isn't. Any clues?

Comment: Hiya, cool so - tracksData.item - is undefined I will look into and update if i find anything; since songs are coming from url it won't be able to delete the song I reckon, check the documentation please as you mentioned; its bit too late at my part of glob now :), cheers!

Comment: Do you mean it is not possible to "modify" the tracksData.item before rendering?

Comment: no I reckon it is possible see this http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/javascript-sdk#delete & right now I am reading this http://static.soundcloud.com/demos/soundcloud-custom-player/js/sc-player.js to see if I can do that from some inbuilt function, you should play around with it as well, it will also be worth asking in their developers blog about this, cheers!